# nginx rewrite url not ending with .html

Tags: html, nginx, url-rewriting

My website new url structur is /p/xxx.html,and origal one is /p/xxx.now I need a rule ,when you visit /p/xxx ,you foward to /p/xxx.html automactily.Here is my rule:

```
rewrite http://t.shareae.cn/p/.*(?<!html)$  http://t.shareae.cn/p/$1\.html permanent;
```

Unfortunately，It dose not work! the url will endding with much ".html".

```
http://t.shareae.cn/p/abc.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html
```

Comment: try to replace `permanent` by `last`

Comment: This rewrite never match anything. Look for other places where you could send redirect.